# "Parece OK" ou não?

Tags: debate

Sinceramente, eu não entendi o que aconteceu [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48944/como-evitar-uma-pagina-carregar-at%C3%A9-ser-dada-a-confirma%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-alert).
Eu nem ia comentar sobre o ocorrido mas agora que fui ver, a mesma está sendo votada para ser fechada por motivo "Amplo demais".

Na minha opinião essa pergunta tem uma qualidade muito baixa e dificilmente será útil futuramente da forma como está descrita. Primeiro que a "pergunta" em evidência nem é uma pergunta, não há dúvidas, não é perguntado nada, somente há vários links seguido de um "não sei fazer".

Por conta disso levantei um sinalizador por "qualidade baixa", esperando uma (possível) exclusão.
Acontece que meu sinalizador para essa pergunta foi "disputado". Depois de entender [o que é, e, o que deve acontecer para um sinalizador ser disputado](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag/95277#95277) tive certeza que o motivo foi essa análise:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24541

Agora eu fiquei confuso. Se a pergunta "parecia OK", por que há 4 votos para fechá-la por ser ampla demais? O sinalizador que levantei foi útil ou não?

Comment: Eu rejeitei a sua sinalização pois era muito cedo para fechar a pergunta, na minha opinião o certo seria dar tempo ao *OP* para melhorar a questão, algo que não aconteceu e por isso votei para fechar ela. Ambas as respostas dessa [**pergunta**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/537/quanto-tempo-esperar-antes-de-votar-para-fechar-uma-pergunta) ilustram bem o que quero dizer. =)

Comment: A fila de análise é para ação imediata nas postagens, foi construída com essa filosofia. "Parece OK" é para os casos em que a pergunta não precisa de nenhuma intervenção. Outras opções que poderiam ter sido usadas na fila de baixa qualidade seriam comentar ou editar (não necessariamente fechar, concordo que era cedo). @QMechanic73

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sinalização e fechamento são coisas diferentes. E pessoas têm opiniões diferentes.

Na minha opinião a pergunta é ruim e na forma atual deveria ser fechada. Não acredito que mais do que isto deveria ser feito. Tanto que não fiz e nem mesmo votei para fechar.

Porque eu acho que deveria se fechada mas não votei? Porque eu só costumo votar para fechar quando não há salvação. Assim como eu só costumo votar negativo (às vezes positivo também) depois quando não vejo como aquilo possa mudar.

Depois de um tempo se eu voltar ali e ver que não salvou, eu posso votar. Claro que isto deixará coisas ruins abertas. Mas dado o comportamento robótico de alguns usuários, colocar algo na fila é praticamente sentenciar a pergunta à morte. E nem sempre é fácil reabrir.

Eu uso a política de deixar ver o que acontece na maioria das vezes. Nem sempre, cada caso é um caso. Depende da minha vontade de fazer algo no momento também.

Não sei se votar como "Parece Ok* seria o melhor nestes casos. Talvez pular ou não escolher nada seria melhor. Talvez ajudar a melhorar. Esta escolha está dando o aval à pergunta. Se é a intenção, ok. Mas se a intenção é não fazer nada agora, esperar, parece estranho dizer que está ok.

Não veja nada intrinsecamente errado aí. No fim acho que tudo seguiu o curso normal mesmo que por linhas tortas.

Comment: Para deixar claras as linhas tortas deste caso específico: a pergunta primeiro foi sinalizada como de baixa qualidade, e foi para fila de análise correspondente. De lá, saiu ilesa. Mais tarde recebeu um voto de fechamento e foi para a fila de fechamento, onde recebeu os outros quatro votos. Nesse meio tempo eu deixei um comentário para o autor, esperando que ele editasse a pergunta. Nem ele, nem mais ninguém fez isso, então foi justo ela terminar fechada.

Comment: Essa discução sobre fechamento é ampla de mais(vocês entenderam néh?)... Já foi bastante discutido em varios topicos do meta, mas não se chega a nenhuma conclusão, então o melhor é cada um fazer aquilo que acredita ser melhor pra comunicade. São muitas pessoas com opiniões bastante distintas sobre o assunto, acredito que quando alguem toma a iniciativa baseado em sua opinião sobre o que fazer, os grupos que pensam de forma diferente não deveriam interferir, pois assim poderiamos medir os resultados de cada método de abordagem e chegar a uma conclusão finalmente.